# share transaction across threads

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, oracle, transactions

I currently have a C# process that is saving millions of records to Oracle, currently all in a single thread and within a transaction.   I am interested in doing some parallel processing on this where I can split the data across threads.   Will an ADO.NET/Oracle transaction work properly across the threads?  Do I just create the transaction on the main thread, or do I need to also create a sub-transaction for each thread?

Any experience with this providing some performance improvements, or is the bottleneck Oracle itself.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I would like to have specified Oracle and C# in the title,  they are sorta pertinent to my question.  I understand it may come up in searches, but for the casual developer just scanning titles it would seem to help.

Comment: Ron, we've found that it does not help. Besides, [so] has better tools that "scanning titles". Questions in your favorite tags are highlighted in the questions list; ignored tags are either dimmed or simply hidden. Also, a readable title is simply a lot more likely to get your question answered.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is, essentially:

```
for each record
    add record to database
```

Then it's unlikely that adding multiple threads is going to be of much help. You *might* be able to get performance increase with two threads, when one is gathering and transmitting one record while the other's record is being inserted. But it's unlikely that the overlap would be huge.

You're much better off doing something like:

```
while not end of records
    add 1,000 records to block
    call stored proc to insert 1,000 records
```

That should speed things up quite a bit because you reduce the amount of back-and-forth between client and server.

The way to speed it up beyond that probably isn't to create multiple threads that run the loop, but rather to issue an asynchronous call so that the database can be doing the inserts while you're creating the next block of records. Something like this:

```
while not end of records
    add 1,000 records to block
    wait for pending asynchronous call to complete
    issue asynchronous call to insert 1,000 records
```

There are many different ways to issue that asynchronous call. I would recommend using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### Edit

It occurs to me that you might have a problem trying to keep a transaction alive across asynchronous calls. If so, then you do the database insert on the main thread, and have the asynchronous task fill the buffer. It looks like this:

```
start transaction
buffer = fill_buffer(); // this is synchronous
while buffer.count > 0
{
    task = start asynchronous task to fill the next buffer
    call database to insert records from buffer
    buffer = task.result  // waits for task to complete
}
end transaction
```

This technique ensures that all database calls for the transaction occur on the main thread.

Comment: thanks, great info.  I want to try the array binding feature where I can send the 1000 records in one shot. I too was thinking that the threads may not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be, if you can (your workplace allows it), write this as a pl/sql procedure using bulk inserts instead of relying on a middleware app. The improvement will be huge as long as is coded well.

If you have to use a middleware (.net), I recommend you use ODP.NET [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) since ADO.NET-to-Oracle is deprecated (if I am not mistaken). In addition, ODP.NET will give you a boost in performance because it uses oracle 11g new features and improvements.

As far as middleware, I never done any parallel threading, but I suspect you will have transactions issues with oracle (since you are inserting and the way relational databases work). I know it is possible, but for the extra effort, it is just better to move the processing to the database and let oracle do its magic.

Comment: thanks. Just too much processing of data on server side to move to the database. Considered bulk copy but it doesn't work in a transaction. A very large transaction may also be part of the problem. Currently trying the array binding where send multiple rows in one call, having an issue here, but hope to see how this turns out soon.  If this works, then would like to parallel this also in hopes to speed things up.  Would the pl/sql bulk insert routine be the same as the odp.net array binding support?  e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html